# Can we divide both sides of positive semidefinite inequality elementwise by another psd matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, semidefinite-programming

Assume we have positive semidefinite matrices $A,B,C$ and we have $A \circ B \ge C$.  Is it correct that $A \ge C \oslash B$. In particular, for a vector $r$ and inequality, $ A \circ B \ge r \cdot r^T$. What can be said about $A$? Is $ A \ge r \cdot r^T \oslash B $  true?  Where $C\ge D$ means $C-D\ge0$ is a positive semidefinite matrix,i.e. $\ge$ is in the semidefinite sense.$\odot$ is elementwise product and $\oslash$ is elementwise division.

Comment: What does the circle mean? Hadamard product? And what does the slashed circle mean? And does semidefinite mean positively semi definite or could they be negatively semi definite?

Comment: @mathreadler, Circle mean Hadamard product. And Slashed circle mean Hadamard divide,i.e. elementwise division. By semidefinite I mean positive semidefinite.

Comment: Ok. And then what does >= mean, elementwise inequality? Well $r \cdot r^T$ is positive semi definite and rank 1. That's all I can say for sure so far. I have some hadamard product relations in the back of my head somewhere. Will tell if they pop up.

Comment: >= is in the semidefinite sense. I mention it in the question. Thank you.